# Redux async issue when getting the current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am having an asynchronous issue while getting the state in my component. When I console log in the mapStateToProps, it comes out fine but when I console log inside my render... it comes as the old state. How can I chain functions in the redux?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes'
import HomePage from './HomePage'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import * as actions from '../actions/listingActions.js'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.listings.length === 0) {
    this.props.actions.fetchListings()
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routes />
        console.log(this.props.listings); // old state gets printed out
        <HomePage listings={this.props.listings} />
      </div>
     );
   }
 }


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state.listings.listings); // comes correctly
  return { listings: state.listings.listings };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)}
}

const WrapperApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default WrapperApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** dispatch your action once you had configured the store:

```
 // const store = createStore(...); // wherever you have this line (often in index.js)
 store.dispatch(actions.fetchListings());
```

And put a placeholder(or render nothing) until it resolves:

```
<Routes />
    {this.props.listings.length? <HomePage listings={this.props.listings} />:null}
 ...
```

**NL;PR:**

When `WrapperApp` is instantiated, `Apps`'s `render` will get called and then `componentDidMount`, thus your dispatch call is scheduled after the first render. Is better to dispatch your fetch(server data requests) actions as soon as possible, they are nonblocking. And while they get loaded, check it in render, and a) show nothing (null) or b) show a placeholder: a loading animation, splash screen, a message...

Comment: where do I import this line?

Comment: What is store here? I am not using configureStore anywhere

Comment: a createStore? somewhere with import {compose, createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';

Comment: I am assuming that your problem is the first render, render eventually gets the right data, right?

Comment: No... i have the component loading on a click and it gets old data every time... i have to click the button twice to get the new data

Comment: is this currenct code? const WrapperApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(App);

Comment: It should be: const WrapperApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

Comment: That was a typo but thats not the issue

Comment: If you are mounting and unmounting WrapperApp, then your condition ```if(this.props.listings.length === 0)``` will not get called when App is remounted. remove it, so the fetch is always triggered. Also, mapStateToProps only will get called when the store changes, that maybe why the second clicks "fixes" really updates the data.

Comment: Where do you use <WrapperApp... />?

Answer (score -1):

bind individual action in `mapDispatchToProps`

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.listings.length === 0) {
        this.props.fetchListings()
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {fetchListings: bindActionCreators(actions.fetchListings, dispatch)}
}
```